# Why is fsck working so inconsistently?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, fsck

Okay, this is hard to describe, so I'll take it point by point.

I got a Linux server, it's running the latest version of Ubuntu. I ran fsck read only to check the hard drive. Here's the output:

```
blackwidower@Twilight:~$ sudo fsck -fn /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Warning!  /dev/sda1 is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Deleted inode 11667059 has zero dtime.  Fix? no

Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong (98319973, counted=98319938).
Fix? no

Inode bitmap differences:  -11667059
Fix? no


/dev/sda1: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

/dev/sda1: 216607/60932096 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 145383835/243703808 blocks
```

So I decided to boot from a Live USB, and run the check from there. The result was... well it said everything was clean, with no errors. I then suspected it was something with the Live USB, so I rebooted the server in recovery mode and the result was the same, clean.

And before anyone asks, yes, I did force the check. It ran through all five steps, and found no errors. But it does find errors when I run internally.

I know there are errors here, but why aren't they being picked up? What exactly is going on? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Does the live USB have the same version of `e2fsck`? Was it checked _while mounted_ like you just did here?

Answer (score 0):

fsck are supposed to be run while filesystem is offline.

If file system is online, data are constantly exchanged between disk and memory.

Some data are in buffer (memory), while other are on disk, this lead to inconsitancies.

In your case, /dev/sda1 must be holding / (root) filesystem, so some data are buffered (/var/log/messages, last logs, cron log ...), hence inconsitancies.

If a fsck from an USB running system, after a clean shutdown reveal nothing, thou shalt have no fear, thy data is safe !

Comment: There's a problem with that. I know there's problems. Likely due to a bad block. I know this because there was one file that would cause the hard drive to crash every time I tried to read it. I'd get some type of I/O error.

I forget the actual error message because I deleted that file.

Comment: `dmesg`command or `/var/log/syslog` should told you if there is a bad block.